# Free Database ERD Creator

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, er-diagram

I am looking for a free option that I can use to design my databases. The following features are a must:

- Needs to be free or under $100
- Able to generate SQL statements to generate the completed database. Preferably, this would support multiple DBMs (MySql, SQLite, etc).
- Visual ERD editor
- Support for unlimited tables

I do not need the program to actually read or manipulate the data; this is purely for designing/building purposes.

As simple as possible would be great because I don't need all of the enterprise-level features.

I have looked at many paid programs already, at least the ones offering free versions, and they're either too limited or too complicated for me and my needs.

**SQL Developer Data Modeler** 
This was just too complex for me; even after looking at a couple of tutorials, I could not even figure out how to add a single entity to my project.

**Visual Paradigm**
This would crash upon launch every time; never got to try it.

**DB Designer Fork**
This was the most promising, but crashed several times while working with it.

Are there any other options?